# How to override ModelChoiceField template?

Tags: python, django, templates

I'd like to override ModelChoiceField template. I have a category model with attributes such as name and depth - categories are nested, and depth tells me how deep into the tree given category is. What I'm trying to do is to indent category name by depth, so if I had two categories - depths 2 and 4, then I'd like to indent their names by 2 and 4 spaces in the select box. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you considered [django mptt](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/)?

it adds a whole bunch of helpers for dealing with tree data, including nice nested widgets

otherwise, i think i've used something like this in the past
(copied form old codebase, so may need tweaking to work. also, think it was written for django 1.2 so probably needs updating)

```
class MyChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return my_fun(obj)

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "my_field":
            kwargs["form_class"] = MyChoiceField
            return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(
            db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Funny story - turns out I can do what I want with this:
def __unicode__(self):
        space = '--' * (self.depth - 1)
                
        return space + ' ' + self.name

Comment: sure. note that editing the `__unicode__` method will affect all places a model is displayed (e.g. elsewhere in the admin) and may look a bit silly. `mptt` also makes certain types of queries more efficient than recursive db lookups, and helps avoid accidental cycles in your tree

Comment: Actually I'm using treebeard and it's MP_Node class, so I think the code is already efficient, but mptt seems to be a cool package, so I'll keep it in mind. Thanks for help!